# remove Array object content dictionary with null value iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, json, dictionary, null

I have Json object like this :

```
{
    CO = 1;
    CUABR = "<null>";
    CUNO = "<null>";
    DIV = 2;
    DLDAT = 1020923;
    SALID = "<null>";
    "form_number" = MM23000;
    type = VHNO;
},
    {
    CO = 1;
    CUABR = "<null>";
    CUNO = "<null>";
    DIV = 2;
    DLDAT = 1020923;
    SALID = "<null>";
    "form_number" = MM23001;
    type = VHNO;
},
    {
    CO = 1;
    CUABR = "<null>";
    CUNO = "<null>";
    DIV = 2;
    DLDAT = 1020924;
    SALID = "<null>";
    "form_number" = MM23002;
    type = VHNO;
},
    {
    CO = 1;
    CUABR = "\U53f0\U5316\U65b0\U6e2f";
    CUNO = FCFC3;
    DIV = 2;
    DLDAT = 1020924;
    SALID = M;
    "form_number" = MM23003;
    type = VHNO;
}
```

}

then I need to remove json array content null dictionary key value to sort like this:

```
{
    CO = 1;
    CUABR = "\U53f0\U5316\U65b0\U6e2f";
    CUNO = FCFC3;
    DIV = 2;
    DLDAT = 1020924;
    SALID = M;
    "form_number" = MM23003;
    type = VHNO;
}
```

}

How should I do? 
I would like to know the proper way, should I use nest loop or block?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please improve the quality of your question. What do you want to filter on? The value of `CUABR`? What language are you using? What do your model classes look like?

Answer (score 0):

use this may help you..

```
 NSMutableArray *newarray=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in parseArrray)
    {
        if (dictionary[key] != [NSNull null]) {
            [newarray addObject:dictionary];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cool, I just make a new array. Thanks so much!!